# Which control board can I put in my Whirlpool washing machine?

Tags: repair, washing-machine

I have a Whirlpool washing machine, model number WFW8300SW03, which is 9 years old but in good condition except that it shows error code F-01 on the last drain of every cycle. The service manual suggests that to fix this I need to replace the central control unit (CCU). I have done extensive tests and research to determine that nothing short of replacing the CCU is likely to fix this error.

Some sources I've found say that the part number for the CCU is W10160252 and others say that it's W10205839. Here's [one page that lists both numbers](https://www.pwslaundry.com/files/manuals/residential/maytag-whirlpool/Whirlpool-WFW8300SW03-03-CONTROL-PANEL-PARTS.pdf); it says the former is the original part number and the latter is the replacement part number. And then, to complicate matters, [Sears lists](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/part-number/W10160252/0026/110.html) yet another part number, W10525351, as a replacement for W10160252.

Question: are any of these three parts (W10160252, W10205839, W10525351) suitable as a replacement CCU?

It'd also be nice to know what the differences between them are, if possible. I'm finding a very large disparity in price between them; just for example, Sears sells the W10525351 for $110 and the W10205839 for over $240. Obviously I wouldn't want to spend $240 on a part if a $110 equivalent would work just as well.

---

I'm actually doing this to help out a family member, who owns the machine, but I don't think that matters so I've written the question as though it were mine.

Comment: You should contact Whirlpool as they are probably the only source that knows the differences between these part numbers.

Comment: I like repairclinic.com for appliance parts. They have a generous return policy if you don't get the right part. Oddly they list a another different part number for your board.

Comment: @Mysterfxit Interesting, what did you find from them? I did a [search for the washer model number](https://www.repairclinic.com/Shop-For-Parts/a11b5d697212/Model-WFW8300SW03-Whirlpool-Washing-Machine-Parts?n=2) and it came up with 10205839 and 10525351 for the CCU, the same part numbers I've been finding elsewhere.

Comment: I searched for your model number and filtered by  "circuit board and timer". I got this: https://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Whirlpool-Washing-Machine-User-Control-And-Display-Board/WP8571903/1180620?modelNumber=WFW8300SW03&ss=a11b5c13d697212&mr=1

Comment: @Mysterfxit Ah, that's the front control panel, not the central control unit. It's a different part of the machine from what I need (as far as I can tell).